# React useEffect throws error: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I am using react-native for my spotify api app and when I want to get data from my server with `axios` (in `useEffect` because I want to render the returned items when the component loads) it throws error: `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function`. So if anyone knows how to solve this problem I would be very greatful.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, FlatList, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function ArtistsCom({route}) {
    const type = route.name.toLowerCase();
    const [time, setTime] = useState('short_term');
    const [access_token, setAccess_token] = useState('');
    const [refresh_token, setRefresh_token] = useState('');
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        AsyncStorage.getItem('refresh_token')
        .then(value => setRefresh_token(value));

        const getDataAsync = async () => {
            const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/api/refresh`, {
                headers: {
                    body: {
                        refresh_token: refresh_token
                    }
                }
            })
            console.log(res);
            setAccess_token(res.data.access_token);
            return res;
        };
        getDataAsync();
    }, []);

    return (
        <View>
            <View>
                {!loading ? items.map((item, key) => {
                    return (
                        <View key={key} style={{width: 150, height: 150, margin: 10}}>
                            <Image style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} source={{uri: type == 'artists' ? item.images[0].url : item.album.images[0].url}} />
                            <View style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left:4,  height: 20, width: '100%', backgroudColor: 'red'}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{key+1}. {item.name}</Text></View>
                        </View>
                    )
                }) : <Text>Loading...</Text>}
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Is this your complete code? The only state update I see is `setRefresh_token(value)` when you retrieve the refresh token from storage. If it's the axios call then you can use a cancel token and kill the inflight requests when the component unmounts.

Comment: It's my bad. In the code I don't `setItems()`. The problem is in `getDataAsync()` (I think)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cancel token to cancel in-flight requests.

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...

  // Create cancel token and source
  const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
  const source = CancelToken.source();

  const getDataAsync = async () => {
    const res = await axios.post(
      `http://localhost:3001/api/refresh`,
      {
        cancelToken: source.token, // <-- attach cancel token to request
        headers: {
          body: {
            refresh_token: refresh_token
          }
        }
      },
    );
    console.log(res);
    setItems(res.data.items);
    return res;
  };
  getDataAsync();

  // Return useEffect cleanup function to cancel request
  return () => {
    source.cancel('Component unmounted'); // message is optional
  };
}, []);
```

### Update

Enclose the asynchronous logic in a `try/catch/finally` to make the multiple requests and handle any rejected promises and errors.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Create cancel token and source
  const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
  const source = CancelToken.source();

  const getDataAsync = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const refresh_token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
      const res = await axios.post(
        `http://localhost:3001/api/refresh`,
        {
          cancelToken: source.token, // <-- attach cancel token to request
          headers: {
            body: {
              refresh_token
            }
          }
        },
      );

      const { access_token } = res.data;
      setAccess_token(access_token);

      const res2 = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/top/${type}?time_range=${time}&limit=50&access_token=${access_token}`);
      setItems(res2.data.items);
    } catch(error) {
      // handle any errors, log them, set some state, etc...
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  getDataAsync();

  // Return useEffect cleanup function to cancel request
  return () => {
    source.cancel('Component unmounted'); // message is optional
  };
}, [refreshToken]);
```

Comment: I did exactly the same but still the same error.

Comment: @Vichmi Are you sure this is the code attempting to update state after unmounting?

Comment: The axios request should return {access_token: token} but the it gives me the error.

Comment: @Vichmi Ah, I think I see part of the issue. Originally you had 2 asynchronous "actions" occurring at the same time, one to get the access token and the other to use the access token and make the requests. The second wasn't waiting for the first. I updated my answer in part based on this, and in part based on the additional code you'd added in your answer, but keeping it still using the `async/await` syntax versus the Promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it all

Here is the code:

```
const type = route.name.toLowerCase();
    const [time, setTime] = useState('short_term');
    const [access_token, setAccess_token] = useState('');
    const [refresh_token, setRefresh_token] = useState('');
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const getItems = (ACCESS_TOKEN) => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/top/${type}?time_range=${time}&limit=50&access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}`)
        .then(res => {
            setItems(res.data.items);
            setLoading(false);
        })
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);

        const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
        const source = CancelToken.source();
        const getRefreshedAccessToken = async() => {
            axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/api/refresh`, {
                cancelToken: source.token,
                headers: {
                    body: {
                        refresh_token: await AsyncStorage.getItem('refresh_token')
                    }
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data.access_token);
                setAccess_token(res.data.access_token);
                getItems(res.data.access_token);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        };
        getRefreshedAccessToken();

        return () => {
            source.cancel('Component unmounted'); 
        }
    }, [refresh_token]);
```

Comment: This is a partial solution, as you should also cancel the second request when the component unmounts.